# Empty row in Mysql table when i inserted data from the HTML form

Tags: python, mysql, django

```
username=request.GET.get('username')
password=request.GET.get('password')
Email=request.GET.get('Email')
conform_password=request.GET.get('conform_password')
mySql_insert_query =  """INSERT INTO loginapp_loginuser ( email, username,pasword,conform_password) VALUES ( Email,username, password, conform_password) """
```

[image]

I am getting empty data instead of actual data in a row I don't know what is the problem with my code, please review it once and give me feedback, thank you for your support

Comment: Why not use the ORM if you are using Django?

Comment: Maybe you should enable the [General Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html), and look at the statement that is actually executed.

Comment: why not using django forms and django orm ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello guys thank you for your response, i got the solution of this problem. we are writing wrong insert query statement. correct statement is

```
INSERT INTO loginapp_loginuser (email, username, password,conform_password) VALUES ('"+Email+"','"+username+"','"+password+"','"+conform_password+"')
```